# Breakpoint not hitting on ItemDataBound function

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a grid control called `RadGrid1` and with a breakpoint in `RadGrid1_ItemDataBound`, but when I run my aspx application, the breakpoint is not being triggered.

my code is:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Width="980px" CssClass="GridDisplay" 
            AllowAutomaticDeletes="false" AllowAutomaticInserts="false" AllowAutomaticUpdates="true" AllowPaging="true" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteColumn="false" AutoGenerateEditColumn="false" ItemStyle-Height="20px" 
            ClientSettings-ActiveRowIndex="true" EnableViewState = "false" OnDeleteCommand = "RadGrid1_OnDelete" 
            OnItemCreated = "RadGrid1_ItemCreated" OnItemDatabound = "RadGrid1_ItemDatabound" OnNeedDataSource = "RadGrid1_NeedDataSource">

    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Confirmed" HeaderText="Confirmed" UniqueName="Confirmed" Visible="true">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkVerified" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
            Checked='<%# bool.Parse(Eval("Verified").ToString()) %>'
            Enabled='<%# !!Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Verified").ToString())) %>'
            ToolTip='<%# Eval("NoConfirmDesc").ToString() %>'
            />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

aspx.cs

```
private void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    { }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you databind the grid on the onload event. Does your grid filled with desired data?

Comment: correct, it is displaying the desired data

Comment: Generally breakpoints trigger in you project?

Comment: please add all the relevant code...

Comment: It's not postback, is it? Also, add a breakpoint where you bind the datasource to the gridview (something like `RadGrid1.DataBind()`) and check if that gets hit.

Comment: I added breakpoint to DataBind() and it is hit. Not a postback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In aspx, the handler for `Databound` event is called `RadGrid1_ItemDatabound`

```
OnItemDatabound = "RadGrid1_ItemDatabound"
```

but in code behind, your method is spelled with capital **B** in *databound*

```
void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound
```

Make sure you place the breakpoint inside the right method.

Comment: Good view! +1 It is totally this. and we lost an hour.. i don't know if laugh or cry!

Comment: wow...... though technically the page should have crashed because of the function in aspx being different from code behind.... don't know why the page didnt crash... Thanks for your help

Comment: @Csharp yes, the page sohuld have crashed. you probably have another method called RadGrid1_ItemDatabound in code behind or in a base class

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot to register or are not correctly registering the OnItemDataBound Event

Or maybe you are not databinding the control?

```
RadGrid1.DataSource= mydatasource;
RadGrid1.DataBind();
```

As last possibility maybe iis express and visualstudio debugger are not working correclty

I suggest to kill iisexpress process and then rebuild the solution then try again

Comment: well, I forgot to mention it in my post... but the aspx page does have OnItemDatabound = "RadGrid1_ItemDatabound"

Comment: I don't understand the last part of your comment.

Comment: kill iis, kill visualstudio then reopen visualstudio, rebuild solution and try to debug

Answer (score 1):

Could you make sure `AutoEventWireup="true"` for the page?

```
<%@ Page ... AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

In addition, make sure that there are not spaces between them `OnItemDatabound="RadGrid1_ItemDatabound"`

One thing I notice in your code is you want to use **[OnNeedDataSource](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-advanced-data-binding.html)** to bind Data if you use RadGrid.

```
OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
```

Comment: OnNeedDataSource exists in my aspx code; The spacing did not make a difference; AutoEventWireup is set to True;

Comment: Does the break point hit to Page_Load event when you use F5? Where is your break point exactly at (could you post the screenshot)?

Comment: Can't post a screenshot... PC is configured to disable screenshot. Yes, the breakpoint is hit on PageLoad.

Comment: My breakpoint is set on "private void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound" and on  "{"

Comment: ***RadGrid1_ItemDataBound event should be protected instead of private***

Comment: I'm out of bullet. ***To debug:*** Create a new page without master page. Then just use only OnNeedDataSource and OnItemDatabound. Set `AutoGenerateColumns="ture"` (Not bound columns or template columns).  Make sure you have data and; otherwise, OnItemDatabound will never get hit if you do not have data. ***Make sure all events are protected***